# How to finish activities up to one specific activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, back, activity-finish

For example, I opened activities A, B, C, D.

I want to finish D and C and return back to B.

I don't want to open activity B with clear tasks and new task flags. I want to keep activity A too so user can return from B to A with back button.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), B.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in B activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Reiz3N.  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `this.finish()` in your activity method `onDestroy()` in C and D classes, then if you go from C to D, Android will finish this Activity and you will go directly from D to B, instead of D to C.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Make a global static `boolean` say closeActivity. Set it to `false` by default. When D is ended set the variable to `true`. In `onResume` of activity C check if variable is set to `true` and if `true`, call `finish()`. Do this until activity B is reached and in `onResume` of B set the `boolean` to `false`